# TypeError: chargebee.subscription.list is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, chargebee

When I'm trying to make request with Chargebee I'm getting an error

> TypeError: this.chargebee.subscription.list is not a function

But it's defined when I'm trying to debug it :[image]

This is function where I'm making the request:

```
 async test(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.chargebee.subscription.list({
        limit: 2,
        "plan_id[in]": ["basic", "no_trial"]
      }).request(function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
          //handle error
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          resolve(result)
          for (var i = 0; i < result.list.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.list[i]
            console.log(entry);
            var subscription = entry.subscription;
            var customer = entry.customer;
            var card = entry.card;
          }
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

Why we have error that function is undefined, when it is defined?
Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Why we have error that function is undefined, when it is defined?

Your error isn't that the function is undefined, it's that `this.chargebee.subscription.list` is not a function. Indeed, take a look at your debugging output: `list = Object {request: }` - it's an object, not a function, yet you're trying to call it as a function: `this.chargebee.subscription.list(...).request(...)`